# How to avoid N+1 Query and Perform Eager Loading on Active Admin Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I am experiencing an [N+1 query problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) in an [Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) ([Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)) form.  The query occurs when loading a select input that corresponds to a `belongs_to` association.  The `display_name` on the associated model references another `belongs_to` association.  Here are the model relationships:

```
:user 
   |-- belongs_to :alum 
                     |-- belongs_to :graduation_class
                                                   |-- year
```

Here are the relevant portions of the models:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :alumn, optional: true, touch: true
  ...
end
```

**app/models/alumn.rb**

```
class Alumn < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :graduation_class, touch: true
  delegate :year, to: :graduation_class
  has_many :users
  ...
  def display_name
    "#{year}: #{last_name}, #{first_name} #{middle_name}"
  end
  ...
end
```

This is the relevant Active Admin class:

**app/admin/user.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  ...
  includes :alumn, alumn: :graduation_class
  ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :alumn  # This is causing the N+1 query
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The generation of the `f.input :alumn` select field is causing an N+1 query on `graduation_class`.  This is because [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) generates the select options by calling `alumn.display_name` which in turn invokes the `year` method on the associated `graduation_class`.

My question is, how can I eager load `graduation_class` in this form?  The `includes :alumn, alumn: :graduation_class` in the Active Admin class does not seem to work.

**Update:**

I can see from the server log, that `GraduationClass` is being loaded, but it still does not eliminate the N+1 query:

```
GraduationClass Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "graduation_classes".* FROM "graduation_classes"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved this by building a custom collection on the `admin` field.  Here is the relevant code:

**app/admin/user.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  ...
  includes :alumn, alumn: :graduation_class
  ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :alumn, as: :select, 
        collection: Alumn.includes(:graduation_class).where(...)
                      .collect { |a| [ a.display_name, a.id ] }
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

It still results in an extra query, but it is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

nested includes are done just by using hashes.

```
includes({:alumn => :graduation_class})
```

Comment: I tried `  includes :alumn, { :alumn => :graduation_class }` and it did not work.

Comment: without the first `:alumn`. Only the hash

Comment: That did not work either.  I can see from the server log that GraduationClass is being  loaded, but for some reason, that does not translate to the form.

Answer (score 2):

If building a Formtastic select input is generating unwanted queries try using pluck to fetch only the fields you need to build the list.

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/20/rails-activeadmin-n-1-query-optimization/

add this to your Active Admin resource, in the controller block

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register(MyResource) do
  # ...

  controller do
    # ...

    def scoped_collection
      super.includes whatever: :you_want
    end
  end
end
```